# Show String Item from ListView onClick

Tags: java, android, listview

I have this on my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MoviesCategoriesActivity">

    <ListView
        android:entries="@array/moviecategories"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this on my class:

```
public class MoviesCategoriesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies_categories);

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

        ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
        first.add("one");
        first.add("two");
        first.add("three");

        ArrayList<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();
        second.add("four");
        second.add("five");
        second.add("six");
    }
}
```

I want to: when I click on the first item from the list to show me a string from the arraylist and when I press the second item to show me a string from the second arraylist. How can be done?

Comment: You should implement this inside a List View adapter, have you implemented one yet?

Comment: @Allie please do some google just search on google **"android listview example"** you will get many link for it

Comment: Thank you all guys.. I will check your answers now :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to create your own adapter for this and you will get the desired answer.

i'd rather suggest you to use recyclerview a.k.a Advanced ListView

[Tutorail](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that use RecyclerView,but you can use listview and get selected item like this way

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // Array of strings storing country names
    String[] countries = new String[] {
        "India",
        "Pakistan",
        "Sri Lanka",
        "China",
        "Bangladesh",
        "Nepal",
        "Afghanistan",
        "North Korea",
        "South Korea",
        "Japan"
    };

    // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
    int[] flags = new int[]{
        R.drawable.india,
        R.drawable.pakistan,
        R.drawable.srilanka,
        R.drawable.china,
        R.drawable.bangladesh,
        R.drawable.nepal,
        R.drawable.afghanistan,
        R.drawable.nkorea,
        R.drawable.skorea,
        R.drawable.japan
    };

    // Array of strings to store currencies
    String[] currency = new String[]{
        "Indian Rupee",
        "Pakistani Rupee",
        "Sri Lankan Rupee",
        "Renminbi",
        "Bangladeshi Taka",
        "Nepalese Rupee",
        "Afghani",
        "North Korean Won",
        "South Korean Won",
        "Japanese Yen"
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
            hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
            hm.put("cur","Currency : " + currency[i]);
            hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
            aList.add(hm);
        }

        // Keys used in Hashmap
        String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

        // Ids of views in listview_layout
        int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

        // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
        ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // Setting the adapter to the listView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Item Click Listener for the listview
        OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View container, int position, long id) {
                // Getting the Container Layout of the ListView
                LinearLayout linearLayoutParent = (LinearLayout) container;

                // Getting the inner Linear Layout
                LinearLayout linearLayoutChild = (LinearLayout ) linearLayoutParent.getChildAt(1);

                // Getting the Country TextView
                TextView tvCountry = (TextView) linearLayoutChild.getChildAt(0);

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tvCountry.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        // Setting the item click listener for the listview
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

For more see this demo http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-itemclicklistener-for-a-listview-with-images-and-text/

Answer (score 0):

For that you can set onItemClicklistener() on listview and based on the item position you can show the values from whatever array you want.

Comment: it's true way
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l)
            {
                switch (position)
                {
                    case 1:
                        //show first array as you want
                        break;
                    case 2: 
                        //show second array as you want 
                        break;
                }
            }
        });